# problem with scrpage2 and coloured borders

Tags: header-footer, color, margins, koma-script, scrpage2

I'm trying to do this

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
%\tikzset{variable/.default=}  
\newcommand{\pageframe}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       % page frame
        \fill[red](current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        \fill[white,rounded corners=1cm]($(current page.north west)+%(1cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1cm,4cm)$);
%       \node[fill=green,text width=1.5cm,text centered] 
%           at ($(current page.south)+(0,4cm)$){\strut\pagemark};
%%       \strut gives all page mark nodes the same hight.  
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
% set page style
\cehead[\pageframe]{\pageframe}
\cohead[\pageframe]{\pageframe}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

but it fails to compile:

```
! Argument of \tikz@cc@parse@factor has an extra }.
```

I don't get it; if I comment the last line, `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`, it compiles, though output remains unmodified...

Comment: The reason for it not compiling is because of the incomplete second `\fill` command. In (La)TeX, `%` represents a comment character, implying that everything after (to the right of) it will be disregarded. You either remove/comment the entire line or understand the command structure of `\fill` to modify it accordingly. Finally, it compiles fine when you comment `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` because the `\pageframe` macro (containing the problematic `\fill`) is only executed once you set the page style to `scrheadings`. If you don't set these headings, the incomplete code is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the percent sign `%` in the second fill line. Here's a compilable version:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\pageframe}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       % page frame
        \fill[red](current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        \fill[white,rounded corners=1cm]($(current page.north west)
            +(1cm,-1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1cm,4cm)$);
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
% set page style
\cehead[\pageframe]{\pageframe}
\cohead[\pageframe]{\pageframe}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\newpage
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: page with frame]